# Creating Environment Variables for IBM DB2 on linux

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu, environment-variables, db2, redhat

I have created a web service using ASP Dot net Core6, and one of its uses was to connect to IBM DB 2, connect to it which is found on another network and execute queries and so on. On windows it works perfectly, I have made it as a service and when the computer turns on, it runs with it, however on linux here's where the pickle comes, I used `systemctl` to add it as a service, on Linux I have to use a different nugget package for it but it's fine, moreover I have to add the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and set it equal to something like `~/Desktop/SomeFolder/clidriver/lib:~/Desktop/SomeFolder/clidriver/lib/icc`
If I add it from the terminal using the `export` command, then run the dotnet dll it works like a charm, however when running it using the `systemctl` it doesn't run because of the environment variable, I have tried to add it to the `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile` and `/etc/environment` but somehow IBM DB2 DLLs can't seem to be able to load it or read it. I don't know what's wrong here why that environment variable is not being read.

I was trying this on Ubuntu, but I need it to work on Ubuntu, RedHat and CentOS.
Furthermore, I have tried to write `Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/Desktop/SomeFolder/clidriver/lib:~/Desktop/SomeFolder/clidriver/lib/icc"` Inside the service file but still did not work.

> Note: When installing this nugget package it only comes with a DLL and a folder `clidriver`, and I don't think that there's a need to download/install anything else, since it worked when I ran the dll from the shell, I ran it using the following command `/snap/bin/dotnet /home/administrator/Desktop/SomeFolder/ep.dll --urls "http://0.0.0.0:9696"`

> Also: After running the command `sudo strings /proc/10155/environ` where `10155` was the PID of the end point when it was running via the `systemctl`, I saw the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` defined to the value I want it to be, but still I don't know what's wrong with it

### [Update]

This is my service file:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
User=administrator
WorkingDirectory=/home/administrator/Desktop/SomeFolder/
Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/Desktop/SomeFolder/clidriver/lib:~/Desktop/SomeFolder/clidriver/lib/icc"
ExecStart=/snap/bin/dotnet /home/administrator/Desktop/SomeFolder/ep.dll --urls "http://0.0.0.0:9696"
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: @mao alright, done

Comment: I suggest you do not use ~ in unit files, but rather abolute paths. Separately it is unclear what edit you made to /etc/environment . Seems the snapd is not picking it up, did you try putting the `Environment=...` line into the effective snapd.service also?

Comment: In the /etc/environment i just added the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as an environment variable no more, like this: LD_LIBRARY_PATH="~/Desktop/Insight/Intalio.Insight.TD/clidriver/lib:~/Desktop/Insight/Intalio.Insight.TD/clidriver/lib/icc"

Comment: @mao I never tried to write anything to snapd.service, actually i never heard of it before, I'm just an average linux user that's all